# Where to use @Transactional annotation and @Repository annotation

Tags: spring, orm, annotations, spring-transactions

Some of the examples on internet use `@Transactional` annotation on DAO implementation methods while some use this annotation for the service layer methods. Where is it more appropriate to put the `@Transactional` and why?

Similarly where to put `@Repository` annotation. On the DAO interface or on the DAO implementation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have always used `@Service` and `@Repository` annotations on their implementations, but they can be put in either one. Although, putting it on a interface would mean that you won't be able to have more than one implementation, because you would get a `NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException` error.

In the case of `@Transactional`, it depends, but normally it goes on the service. If you want to be able to add various DB calls on one transaction, then it should go in the service. If you want to make small transactions, then on the DAO would be best, but then, you wouldn't be able to modify several tables in one single transaction. Another con of having it on the DAO, is that you won't be able to rollback multiple modifications, only the ones that are bing executed by the DAO.

**EDIT**

After several projects using Spring, each one of different proportions, I end up changing my own practices. I would like to add that even though adding `@Transactional` to the service layer isn't exactly bad practice, it can be negatively affect the performance of the application. So in my own experience, it is better to add it to the `DAO/Repository` layers and only add at function level in the **service layer**, if a transaction must be **atomic**.

One more thing, if you are using `Spring Data`, the `@Repository` must be added on the interface. Only if you extend the `JpaRepository` will you need to add the `@Repository` annotation on the implementation. In this case, the interface of the `JpaRepository` and the custom implementation will both have `@Repository`.